# Way to show two tables side-by-side?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

is there a way to show these two tables side-by-side, which would make readability easier?

[Binomial Distribution Parameter & Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301445/binomial-distribution-parameter)

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{}
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{X} & \text{P(X)}\\ 
\hline
\\1 & 0.0768 
\\2 & 0.2304 
\\3 & 0.3456 
\\4 & 0.2592 
\\5 & 0.7776 
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Y} & \text{P(Y)}\\ 
\hline
\\1 & 0.15625 
\\2 & 0.3125 
\\3 & 0.3125 
\\4 & 0.15625 
\\5 & 0.03125 
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be useful to add this to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference? For me at least, it's a useful quick-check resource (not suggesting to close this, just if maybe you'd like to add this as a comment/answer to the other question as well).

Comment: @gnometorule: I have appended a bit about [array nesting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5044) to the FAQ

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `align`
$$\begin{align}
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{X} & \text{P(X)}\\ 
\hline
\\1 & 0.0768 
\\2 & 0.2304 
\\3 & 0.3456 
\\4 & 0.2592 
\\5 & 0.7776 
\end{array}
&\quad\quad
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Y} & \text{P(Y)}\\ 
\hline
\\1 & 0.15625 
\\2 & 0.3125 
\\3 & 0.3125 
\\4 & 0.15625 
\\5 & 0.03125 
\end{array}
\end{align}$$
(Sorry for just copying most of robjohn's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can push `edit` and see how he did that.

Comment: This is really not an answer, but in my opinion the better way to go about it is to right-click the table(s), and then $\mathsf{Show\ Math\ As\ \blacktriangleright TeX\ Commands}$.  (Some might not like the pop-up window that results, but I find it better than changing pages.)